# Difference between redirect() and to_route() in laravel

Tags: laravel

What is the difference between to_route and redirect in Laravel? I'm new to Laravel...

```
return to_route('posts.show', $post_id);  ⭕️
return redirect('posts.show', $post_id);  ❌
```

I thought it was routing correctly, but I don't know when it's not.

Answer (score 2):

`to_route(...)` is just a helper function for:

```
redirect()->route(...);
```

`redirect()` takes a path not a route name as the first argument e.g.

Assuming your using `Route::resource(...)`, this is what the different functions would produce:

```
redirect('posts.show', 1) // http://example.com/posts.show
to_route('posts.show', 1) // http://example.com/posts/1
```